# Radio and Charging Outlet Stopped Working

Tags: honda, audio, accord, fuse, charging

I have a 2000 Honda Accord V6 LX. The radio was working yesterday and the charging outlet was working earlier today, but now neither are. Did some research and I'm assuming it could be a blown fuse. Are there 2 separate fuses that need to be replaced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are typically on the same fuse.  Charging outlet should be listed as a cigarette lighter.

Comment: Just replaced it today and both are working just fine, thank you!